# R: pass chr variable as variable in other data frame

Tags: r, rowwise

Based on the response to [this question that I posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077597/how-to-use-purrr-to-iterate-over-every-combo-of-covariates-and-outcomes-in-lm-re/69077780#69077780) I have something like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)


dataset <- tibble(
  y1=rnorm(n=100),
  y2=rnorm(n=100),
  x1=rnorm(n=100),
  x2=rnorm(n=100),)

outcomes <- dataset %>%
  select(y1,y2) %>% colnames

covars <- dataset %>%
  select(x1,x2) %>% colnames

paramlist <- expand_grid(outcomes, covars)

paramlist %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mod = list(lm(reformulate(outcomes, covars), data = dataset)),
         res = list(broom::tidy(mod)),
         predicted=list(predict(mod)),
         data=list(cbind(dataset,predicted)))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
#>   outcomes covars mod    res              predicted   data          
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <list> <list>           <list>      <list>        
#> 1 y1       x1     <lm>   <tibble [2 x 5]> <dbl [100]> <df [100 x 5]>
#> 2 y1       x2     <lm>   <tibble [2 x 5]> <dbl [100]> <df [100 x 5]>
#> 3 y2       x1     <lm>   <tibble [2 x 5]> <dbl [100]> <df [100 x 5]>
#> 4 y2       x2     <lm>   <tibble [2 x 5]> <dbl [100]> <df [100 x 5]>
```

What I would like to do now is - for each combination of outcomes and covars - I'd like to calculate the mean or sd of the predicted value in data conditional on some value of x1. For example, x1 might be a treatment variable, and I'd like the adjusted mean of the outcome for those with x1=0. The tricky part seems to be that the outcome and conditioning variable differ across rows.

Comment: I would recommend the solution using `nest` + `map` it seems more flexible to do other calculations

Comment: I think if I use nest+map I'll still have the same issue of how to pass something like a chr to the sd function. Like if I map over c("outcome1","outcome2"....) I have to somehow switch the type of "outcome1" so it knows I mean an object, right? idk I'm new to this

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear what's a string and what's not here. If you are in a mutate you can use the `.data` pronoun with strings: `mutate(sd(.data[[stringcolvalue]]))`

Comment: thanks @MrFlick - I've updated the question with a reproducible example. please let me know if I can provide any additional information.